# convert project remote images rather than local?

Tags: json, uiimage

I'm trying to use the project [MosaicUI](https://github.com/betzerra/MosaicUI) in my project,

the problem I'm facing is how to move from loading local images from a json file, to images from my web server ?

Did anyone tried this before may be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AFNetWorking to load images from Websites.
Change the method setModule in MosaicDataView.m like this

```
-(void)setModule:(MosaicData *)newModule
{
module = newModule;

__weak UIImageView *weakImage = imageView;
__weak UIView *weakView = self;
__weak MosaicData *weakModule = module;

UIImage *image = [imageView loadImage:module.tg_id ofType:@"png"];
if (image)
{
    [imageView setImage:image];
}
else
{
    [imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:module.l_cover_url]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
    {
        [weakImage setImage:image];
        CGSize imgFinalSize = CGSizeZero;

        [weakImage saveImage:image withFileName:weakModule.tg_id ofType:@"png"];

        if (image.size.width < image.size.height)
        {
            imgFinalSize.width = weakView.bounds.size.width;
            imgFinalSize.height = weakView.bounds.size.width * image.size.height / image.size.width;

            //  This is to avoid black bars on the bottom and top of the image
            //  Happens when images have its height lesser than its bounds
            if (imgFinalSize.height < weakView.bounds.size.height)
            {
                imgFinalSize.width = weakView.bounds.size.height * weakView.bounds.size.width / imgFinalSize.height;
                imgFinalSize.height = weakView.bounds.size.height;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            imgFinalSize.height = weakView.bounds.size.height;
            imgFinalSize.width = weakView.bounds.size.height * image.size.width / image.size.height;

            //  This is to avoid black bars on the left and right of the image
            //  Happens when images have its width lesser than its bounds
            if (imgFinalSize.width < weakView.bounds.size.width)
            {
                imgFinalSize.height = weakView.bounds.size.height * weakView.bounds.size.width / imgFinalSize.height;
                imgFinalSize.width = weakView.bounds.size.width;
            }
        }

        weakImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imgFinalSize.width, imgFinalSize.height);
        weakImage.center = CGPointMake(weakView.frame.size.width/2, weakView.frame.size.height/2);
    }
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
         NSLog(@"%@",error);
    }];
}

//  Set new title
NSInteger marginLeft = self.frame.size.width / 20;
NSInteger marginBottom = self.frame.size.height / 20;

titleLabel.text = module.title;
titleLabel.font = [self fontWithModuleSize];

CGSize newSize = [module.title sizeWithFont:titleLabel.font constrainedToSize:titleLabel.frame.size];
CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(10+marginLeft,
                            self.frame.size.height - newSize.height - marginBottom,
                            newSize.width-30,
                            newSize.height);
titleLabel.frame = newRect;
}
```